# Can a function operating upon mutable data structure be referentially transparent?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, referential-transparency, cats-effect

I'm working on an network application and designed the following trait to read files from remote machines:

```
trait ReadFileAlg[F[_], Dataset[_], Context]{
  def read(path: String, ctx: Context): F[Dataset[String]]
}

final class NetworkContext{
  private var fileDescriptor: Int = _
  private var inputStream: InputStream = _
  //etc
}

final class ReadFromRemoteHost[F[_]: Sync] extends ReadFileAlg[F, List, NetworkContext]{
  override def read(path: String, ctx: NetworkContext): F[List[String]] = Sync[F].delay(
    //read data from the remote host
  )
}
```

The problem I see here is that the implementation accepts `NetworkContext` as a paramenter which is mutable and contains fields like `fileDescriptor` which is related to a network connection.

Is this function `read` referentially transparent?

I think yes, because the function itself does not provide direct access to a mutable state (it is under `Sync[F].delay`) even though it accepts mutable data structure as an argument.

Comment: No it is not referentially transparent, nor it can be. This has nothing to do with "mutable fields". Only what the function returns is important. If it always returns the same result for same arguments, it is referentially transparent. If it does not, it is not.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But it returns the same (`Sync[F]`) result, no? So the result can be replaced by the function invocation.

Comment: Hmm it looks like I don't understand how Sync works. Is it a monad? If so, why NetworkContext ever needs to be mutable?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `Sync` actually is a typeclass providing an ability to suspend side-effect execution which is also a `Monad`. [Some reference](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/sync.html). In particular, there is an instance of `Sync[IO]` for `IO`. The reason I choose to use `Sync` instead of `IO` is the ability to postpone the actual choosing of `Effect`s. In Scala we have different effect `IO` implementation coming from different libraries (I know at least 3 commonly used)

Comment: OK so it looks like it is indeed referentially transparent, as it just returns a command that, when run, produces side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, the semantics of `read` are

> "When you **apply** me I am pure, however when you **run** me I have a
>   side-effect."

Some say this is a kind of [sleight of hand](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/8ygjcq/can_someone_explain_to_me_the_benefits_of_io/e2bgdq6/):

> ...we simply declare that a function returning an IO type may have
>   arbitrary effects without going into detail in how these come about.
>   The scheme has two consequences: First, the type of a function tells
>   you whether it is referentially transparent or has side-effects when
>   run.

For example, consider the following object with mutable state

```
object Foo {
  var x = 42
}

def f(foo: Foo.type): Int = foo.x
```

We can confirm `f` is not referentially transparent because

```
assert(f(Foo) == 42) // OK
assert(f(Foo) == 42) // OK
...
Foo.x = -11
...
assert(f(Foo) == 42) // boom! Expression f(Foo) suddenly means something else
```

However re-implementing `f` to "suspend" the effect

```
def f(foo: Foo.type): IO[Int] = IO(foo.x)
```

which is similar to

```
def f(foo: Foo.type): Unit => Int = _ => foo.x
```

then

```
magicalAssert(f(Foo) == (_ => foo.x)) // OK
magicalAssert(f(Foo) == (_ => foo.x)) // OK
...
Foo.x = -11
...
magicalAssert(f(Foo) == (_ => foo.x)) // Still OK! Expression f(Foo) did not change meaning
```

Here magical assert is like human brain and does not suffer from halting problem so is able to deduce equality of function behaviour, that is, applying `f` evaluates to value `(_ => foo.x)` which is indeed always equal to value `(_ => foo.x)` even though at some point `Foo.x` was mutated to `-11`.

However, running `f`'s effect we have

```
assert(f(Foo)() == 42) // OK
assert(f(Foo)() == 42) // OK
...
Foo.x = -11
...
assert(f(Foo)() == 42) // boom! expression f(Foo)() suddenly means something else
```

(Note how we are simulating `IO.run` via extra parentheses in `f(Foo)()`)

Hence expression `f(Foo)` is referentially transparent, however expression `f(Foo)()` is not.

Comment: _we simply declare that a function returning an IO type may have arbitrary effects without going into detail in how these come about_ Sounds reasonable!

Comment: Additional note, while outside of the question itself. It is important than on the real program the creation of this mutable state should have been suspended on `F` too. [details](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/06/07/shared-state-in-fp.html)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Agree, otherwise the creation cannot be considered referentially transparent. But unfortunately it is not possible to avoid such mutable states entirely because of the interaction with non-functionally written libraries. The best idea I could find is to introduce a type parameter for that mutable state and provide the actual type definition later.